# Split Image randomly, Matlab

Tags: matlab

i have an image and want to split it into two sets of pixels.
These should randomly containing half of the pixels.

Can anyone help?
Totally newbie in matlab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the number of pixels:

```
npix=length(image); % or npix=prod(size(image));
```

Randomly order them

```
randpix=randperm(npix);
```

Get the sets by using half of the randomn order

```
set1=image(randpix(1:end/2));
set2=image(randpix(end/2+1:end));
```

**NOTE**: This works for grayscale images only, but understanding the idea it can be fairly easily changed to RGB

Comment: i get an error " Error using randperm
Size inputs must be scalar." having an idea what thats about?

Comment: @noclue123 sorry I writtend the code without running it. If you read the docs it solves teh problem. See my edit

Comment: Great, it works! for understanding: 1. on npix you save all pixel-positions? 2. randpix is the randomly ordered pixel-positions? 3. why "randperm" and not just "rand"-function?

Comment: @noclue123 rand generates random numbers, you do not want random numbers you want random ordering of fixed numbers!

Comment: tested it again and realized that it doesn't fit my problem. cause i want to that set1&set2 are not arrays (what they currently are how far i see it), it should be matrizes: possible?

Comment: @noclue123 How can you divide a matrix in 2 choosing random pixels and order them in a matrix? how would you order them? Possible if you describe the problem